# How to Prove $(GG^H +I_M)^{-1} g_k = \frac {R_k^{-1} g_k}{g^h_kR_k^{-1}g_k+1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, signal-processing

```
where
 G is MXK matrix,  g_k is kth colum of G, I_M is MXM identity matrix

  and H denotes the conjugate transpose (hermitian operator)
```

and     $R_k= \sum_{i=1, i\neq k}^{K}g_ig_i^H +I_M$

and R_k is same as G except kth column removed.

Note: It is used in MMSE estimation for MIMO and reference said that it require Woodbury matrix identity[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caaOb.png) to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [block matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) we can write $GG^H$ as

$$ GG^H + I_M=
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1\ \cdots \ g_k
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
g_1^H\\ 
\vdots\\ 
g_k^H
\end{bmatrix} + I_M =
\sum_{i=1}^{K} g_i g_i^H + I_M = R_k + g_k \cdot g_k^H$$

Now, we can apply the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) using $A = R_k$, $U = g_k$, $C=1$ and $V=g_k^H$

$$\left( R_k + g_k \cdot g_k^H \right)^{-1} =
R_k^{-1} - R_k^{-1}g_k \left(1 + g_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k \right)^{-1}g_k^H R_k^{-1} = 
R_k^{-1} - \frac{R_k^{-1}g_kg_k^H R_k^{-1}}{1 + g_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k}
$$

Finally, multiplying by $g_k$ we reach the result

$$ \begin{align*}
\left( GG^H + I_M \right)^{-1}g_k &=
\left( R_k + g_k \cdot g_k^H \right)^{-1}g_k =
R_k^{-1}g_k - \frac{R_k^{-1}g_kg_k^H R_k^{-1}g_k}{1 + g_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k} \\ &=
\frac{R_k^{-1}g_k + R_k^{-1}g_kg_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k - R_k^{-1}g_kg_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k}{1 + g_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k}\\ &=
\frac{R_k^{-1}g_k}{1 + g_k^H R_k^{-1} g_k}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: @ Sotiris Thanks you very much, This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You are more than welcome @DEEPAK! :)